# Cross-Validation estimate for the risk is almost unbiased

Tags: cross-validation, expected-value, risk, generalization-error

Let 
$Z_N$ : set with N elements; full training set 
$Z^l_{N/L}$ : set with N/L elements; l-th hold-out set 
$Z_{N(1-1/L)}$ : set with N-N/L elements; e.g. 4/5 of data 
$Z_N \setminus Z^l_{N/L}$ : full set without the l-th hold-out set \

In my lecture notes I have the CV estimation for the risk given as

\begin{equation}
R_{L-CV}(Z_N) = \frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L \frac{L}{N} \sum_{z \in Z^l_{N \setminus L}} \mathcal{L} (y, g(x; w_l(Z_N \setminus Z^l_{N/L})))
\end{equation}

along with the statement that it is an "almost unbiased" estimate for the risk, meaning that

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)}}[R_{gen}(g(.; w(Z_{N(1-1/L)}))] = \mathbb{E}[R_{L-CV}(Z_N)]
\end{equation}

The proof is given by rewriting the left side as

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)}}[R_{gen}(g(.; w(Z_{N(1-1/L)}))] 
&= \mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)} \cup z}[\mathcal{L}(y, g(x; w(Z_{N(1-1/L)}))] \\
&\stackrel{*}{=} \mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)}} \mathbb{E}_{Z_{N/L}} \left[\frac{L}{N} \sum_{z \in Z_{N/L}} \mathcal{L}(y,g(x; w(Z_{N(1-1/L)})) \right]
\end{align}

and the right side as

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[R_{L-CV}(Z_N) 
&=\mathbb{E}_{Z_N}[\frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L \frac{L}{N} \sum_{z \in Z_{N/L}^l} \mathcal{L}(y, g(x; w_l(Z_{N} \setminus Z_{N/L}^l))] \\
&= \frac{1}{L} \sum_{l=1}^L \mathbb{E}_{Z_{N}} \left[ \frac{L}{N}\sum_{z \in Z_{N/L}^l} \mathcal{L}(y, g(x; w_l(Z_{N} \setminus Z_{N/L}^l)) \right] \\
&\stackrel{**}{=}\mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)}} \mathbb{E}_{Z_{N/L}} \left[\frac{L}{N} \sum_{z \in Z_{N/L}} \mathcal{L}(y,g(x; w(Z_{N(1-1/L)})) \right]
\end{align}

However, I do not understand what is meant by $\mathbb{E}_{Z_{N(1-1/L)}}$ and consequently why the equalities $*$ and $**$ hold.